# HBase 1.2 - Deleting Cell with Visibility Label

Tags: shell, hbase

In HBase 1.2, I have:

- A user *testShellUser* with global privileges 'RW' and the following authorization: testShell_visY
- A cell in table *testShellTable* with the following visibility label: testShell_visY

Here's "proof" of the *testShellUser*'s authorizations and privileges:

```
hbase(main):001:0> get_auths 'testShellUser'
testShell_visY
0 row(s) in 1.3290 seconds

hbase(main):003:0> user_permission 'testShellTable'
User                               Namespace,Table,Family,Qualifier:Permission
 testShellUser                     default,testShellTable,,: [Permission: actions=READ,WRITE]
 hbase                             default,testShellTable,,: [Permission: actions=READ,WRITE,EXEC,CREATE,ADMIN]
```

2 row(s) in 0.2210 seconds

When logged in to HBase shell as *testShellUser*, I can see the cell:

```
hbase(main):009:0> scan 'testShellTable'
ROW                                COLUMN+CELL
 2                                 column=cf:name, timestamp=1500315396737, value=Wilma
```

While authenticated as *testShellUser*, I am *unable to delete* the cell -- that is, the command below does nothing:

```
delete 'testShellTable', '2', 'cf:name', 1500315396737
```

Is there a command or a variation of the command above which would allow *testShellUser* to delete this cell (without elevating the user's privileges/authorizations or removing the visibility label from the cell)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with the HBase shell, I seem to have found the "solution."

It seems that, if a cell has a visibility string, then for a *delete* command to delete the cell, the *delete* command must be provided with a visibility string criterion that matches the cell's visibility string. So for the case that I mentioned in the original question, the following *delete* command must be used:

```
delete 'testShellTable', '2', 'cf:name', 1500315396737, {VISIBILITY=>'testShell_visY'}
```

As a side note, it also seems that a user can delete a cell that isn't visible to the user. If, in my case, the user had instead had the authorization string "testShell_visX", then the user's scan of "testShellTable" would not have displayed the cell, but the aforementioned delete command would still have deleted the cell.